# How to solve client fetch error for next-auth authentication

Tags: mongodb, next-auth

I have created an app that connects to a mongodb cluster and stores user info. The user is then able to log in with Next-Auth functionality. The app was working just fine before deploying to Vercel. On the live site I ran into some Server Config Errors. I refractored my code yet I am still running into a few errors.

I am successfully able to connect to the database for a new user sign up.

```
import {
  connectToDatabase,
  hashedPassword,
} from "../../helper/HelperFunctions";

const isEmpty = (value) => value.trim() === "";

const isTenChars = (value) => value.trim().length >= 10;

const emailValidation = (value) => {
  const pattern = /^[^ ]+@[^ ]+\.[a-z]{2,3}$/;

  if (value.match(pattern)) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
};

export default async function handler(req, res) {
  if (req.method == "POST") {
    let data = req.body;

    const { firstName, lastName, email, password, userName } = data;

    const firstNameIsValid = !isEmpty(firstName);
    const lastNameisValid = !isEmpty(lastName);
    const emailIsValid = emailValidation(email);
    const passwordisValid = isTenChars(password);
    const userNameIsValid = !isEmpty(userName);

    let userDataIsValid =
      firstNameIsValid &&
      lastNameisValid &&
      emailIsValid &&
      passwordisValid &&
      userNameIsValid;

    if (!userDataIsValid) {
      return;
    }

    const client = await connectToDatabase();

    const db = client.db();

    const existingUser = await db.collection("users").findOne({ email: email });

    if (existingUser) {
      res.status(422).json({ message: "User already exists, please log in!" });
      console.log("User already exists, please log in!");
      client.close();
      return;
    }

    const protectedPassword = await hashedPassword(password);

    await db.collection("users").insertOne({
      firstName: firstName,
      lastName: lastName,
      email: email,
      password: protectedPassword,
      userName: userName,
    });

    client.close();

    res.status(201).json({ message: "Signed up!" });
  } else {
    res.status(200).json({ data: req.body });
  }
}
```

Here is my nextauth api route

```
import NextAuth from "next-auth/next";
import CredentialsProvider from "next-auth/providers/credentials";

// Helper Functions
import {
  connectToDatabase,
  comparePasswords,
} from "../../../helper/HelperFunctions";

export default NextAuth({
  session: { strategy: "jwt" },
  providers: [
    CredentialsProvider({
      async authorize(credentials) {
        const client = await connectToDatabase();

        const userCollection = client.db().collection("users");

        const user = await userCollection.findOne({
          email: credentials.email,
        });

        if (!user) {
          client.close();

          throw new Error("No user found!");
        }

        const isValid = await comparePasswords(
          credentials.password,
          user.password
        );

        if (!isValid) {
          client.close();

          throw new Error("Invalid password");
        }

        client.close();

        if (user) {
          return {
            email: user.email,
          };
        } else {
          return null;
        }
      },
    }),
  ],
});
```

Before I deployed my site on Vercel, this was working just fine on localhost. The user should then proceed to a new page if the result of logging in has no errors.

```
const result = await signIn("credentials", {
      redirect: false,
      email: form.email,
      password: form.password,
    });

    if (!result.error) {
      console.log(true);
      router.replace("/suggestions");
    } else {
      console.log(result.error);
      setLoginResult(result.error);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you see CLIENT_FETCH_ERROR make sure you have configured the NEXTAUTH_URL environment variable.

when developing you set it to localhost:3000, now you need to set that to your deployed url.

Comment: Where do I configure the NEXTAUTH_URL?

Comment: in your .env file

Comment: https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/options, check this

Comment: I created an .env.local file and stored my live site url. Yet on the live site I am still getting a server error page when logging in :/

Comment: when deploying in nextjs you need to create .env.production or try with only .env

Comment: So frustrating. This was working before launching on vercel..

Answer (score 0):

The problem for me was with the NEXTAUTH_URL. For some reason, other variables in the .env-local can be surrounded by quotes (" ") but the NEXTAUTH_URL CAN'T. So i just removed it an it worked. The anoying part is that you don't see this in the terminal

Answer (score 0):

Try to keep the following things in mind to set configurations of your next-auth app for production.

> 1. set NEXTAUTH_URL='<your_production_domain>' (add this line after localhost url or you may overwrite it)
> 2. provide the full url for any fetch function in your app using process.env.NEXTAUTH_URL like below.

```
const res = await fetch(process.env.NEXTAUTH_URL + '/api/user', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({...})
});
```

> 3. Move all your environment variables from .env.local file to .env file
> 4. Surround all your environment variables with quotation.

In my case, following these steps solved all type of fetch error issues.