# Next-AUTH UNTRUST_HOST_ERROR on AWS Amplify

Tags: amazon-web-services, next.js, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify, next-auth

Deployed NextJS app on AWS Amplify

I am getting untrust host in my CloudWatch logs.

Can someone help?

**[next-auth][error][UNTRUST_HOST_ERROR]**
[image]

URL: https://master.dtzbr8sfj0q7k.amplifyapp.com/

[image]

I have added this domain in my Cognito allowed callbacks.

[image]

**package.json**

```
"next": "13.0.7",
"next-auth": "^4.18.6",
```

**Build Settings**

```
version: 1
applications:
  - frontend:
      phases:
        preBuild:
          commands:
            - npm ci
        build:
          commands:
            - npm run build
            - COGNITO_CLIENT_ID=${COGNITO_CLIENT_ID}
            - COGNITO_CLIENT_SECRET=${COGNITO_CLIENT_SECRET}
            - COGNITO_DOMAIN=${COGNITO_DOMAIN}
            - JWT_SECRET=${JWT_SECRET}
            - NEXTAUTH_URL=${NEXTAUTH_URL}
      artifacts:
        baseDirectory: .next
        files:
          - '**/*'
      cache:
        paths:
          - node_modules/**/*
    appRoot: client
```

**/pages/api/[...nextauth].js**

```js
import NextAuth from "next-auth/next";

function CognitoProvider(options) {
  return {
    id: "cognito",
    name: "Cognito",
    type: "oauth",
    wellKnown: `${options.issuer}/.well-known/openid-configuration`,
    idToken: true,
    profile(profile) {
      return {
        id: profile.sub,
        name: profile.name,
        email: profile.email,
        image: profile.picture,
      };
    },
    options,
  };
}

export default NextAuth({
  providers: [
    CognitoProvider({
      clientId: process.env.COGNITO_CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.COGNITO_CLIENT_SECRET,
      issuer: process.env.COGNITO_DOMAIN,
    }),
  ],
  secret: process.env.JWT_SECRET,
  callbacks: {
    jwt({ token, account, profile }) {
      if (account) {
        console.log("Account exists");
        // modify token
        token.role = profile["cognito:groups"];
      }
      return token;
    },

    session({ session, token }) {
      if (session.user) {
        // modify session
        session.user.roles = token.role;
      }
      return session;
    },
  },
});
```

**/index.js**

```js
import Head from "next/head";
import App from "../components/App/App";
import { useSession, signIn, signOut } from "next-auth/react";

export default function Home() {
  const { data: session } = useSession();
  if (session) {
    return (
      <>
        <Head>
          <title>Create Next App</title>
          <meta name="description" content="Generated by create next app" />
          <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
          <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
        </Head>
        <App />
      </>
    );
  }
  return (
    <>
      Not signed in <br />
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          e.preventDefault();
          signIn("cognito", {
            callbackUrl: process.env.NEXTAUTH_URL,
          });
        }}
      >
        Sign in
      </button>
    </>
  );
}
```

Any Help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem today and I found this solution that worked for me:

I had to edit the amplify.yml in build settings and set env variables inside a .env file as below:

```yaml
version: 1
frontend:
  phases:
    preBuild:
      commands:
        - npm ci
    build:
      commands:
        - echo "NEXTAUTH_URL=$NEXTAUTH_URL" >> .env
        - echo "JWT_SECRET=$JWT_SECRET" >> .env
        - npm run build
  artifacts:
    baseDirectory: .next
    files:
      - '**/*'
  cache:
    paths:
      - node_modules/**/*
```

I had to do it for all of my environment variables to allow my Next.js application to access them.

Hope it helped.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have configured `NEXTAUTH_URL` environment variable correctly on AWS Amplify.

I checked your website, and I see this error:
[image: error screenshot]

### CLIENT_FETCH_ERROR

On NextAuth.js documentation,
[image: NextAuth documentation]

---

Here's a similar case:
[How to solve client fetch error for next-auth authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72116901/how-to-solve-client-fetch-error-for-next-auth-authentication)

---

### Update

Sorry for the late reply. These links might give you a little more information about the issue.

[Similiar Case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73983022/nextauth-deployed-on-aws-amplify-next-autherrorclient-fetch-error)

[Environment Variables User Guide on AWS Amplify](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amplify/latest/userguide/environment-variables.html#setting-env-vars)

[image]

Comment: The untrust issue reported on the server is probably because of the URL setting. Let me know if it doesn't work.

Comment: This is my env configuration https://i.ibb.co/7rN7jCQ/2023-01-26-11-12-14-AWS-Amplify-console-Brave.png

Comment: In my local env NEXTAUTH_URL=http://localhost:3000 works but in deployed the same does not work

Comment: @ArihantJain Sorry for the late reply. This link might give you a little more information about the issue. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73983022/nextauth-deployed-on-aws-amplify-next-autherrorclient-fetch-error
\n
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amplify/latest/userguide/environment-variables.html#setting-env-vars